# Delete Elements from Vector Inside Loop

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector, `words_in_family`, of type: `vector<vector<string>>`. I am trying to delete every element of `words_in_family` that is not equal to the string vector `largest_family`, but am having issues and am unsure of why. Any help is appreciated.

```
for (int i = words_in_family.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (words_in_family[i] != largest_family)
    {
        words_in_family.erase(words_in_family[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue you have?

Comment: 'vector<string, vector<string>>' ... the vector declaration is wrong..  you should get compilation error. Can you specify how did you declare the vector

Comment: @SauravSahu I have an error under the `.erase.` that mentions something about an overloaded function and the code runs, but the deletion of the vector elements does not happen.

Comment: @SabyasachiBehera Sorry, that was a mistake. Should be fixed now.

Comment: I'll post this as a comment, because you should be able to do it the way you want so I assume you'll get an answer to that at some point, but is it not more efficient to just create a new one-vector element and swap it with the one you have, or clear the vector and then push `largest_family`?

Comment: [`erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) takes an *iterator* to the element to be erased. Not a value.

Comment: consider using `remove_if` (en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) in the erase-remove idiom instead of the handwritten loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`erase` method doesn't take value. Instead use iterator as parameter for `erase` method:

```
vector<vector<string>>::iterator it = words_in_family.begin();
for (int i = words_in_family.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (words_in_family[i] != largest_family)
    {
        words_in_family.erase(it+i);
    }
}
```

> iterator erase (iterator position); 
>   iterator erase (iterator first, iterator last);

Note that the iterators for std::vector are random access iterators so you can add/subtract integral values to get other valid iterators.

Answer (score 1):

C++ `std::vector` erase an element, in your case:

Erase an element from a vector(`words_in_family`) whose value is equal to `largest_family`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::iterator Itr;
for(Itr = Words_in_family.begin(); Itr != Words_in_family.end();)
{
    if(*Itr == largest_family)
    {
        Itr = Words_in_family.erase(Itr);
    }
    else
    {
        Itr++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words_in_family.erase(words_in_family.begin()+i, words_in_family.begin()+i+1);
```

erase takes iterator as an argument